# SQL запрос, который выведет номер документа, где все значения в join таблице = NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql

СУБД PostgreSQL.

Таблица `info`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица `addon`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Связаны между собой по `id`.

Вопрос: как найти нужный `ID` документа в таблице `info`, для которого в таблице `addon` все записи в поле `item` равны NULL.

Т.е. я должен найти именно 44 айди документа в `info`, тк для 45-го документа минимум 1 запись не равна NULL в таблице `addon`.

Получается только для хотя бы 1 записи, а для всех - не понятно как...

```
select id from info i 
join addon a using(id)
where a.item is null
group by id
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT id
FROM info
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL
    FROM addon
    WHERE info.id = addon.id
      AND addon.item IS NOT NULL
    )
```

Comment: Гениально, спасибо :)

Comment: :-( а у меня???

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT info.ID
FROM info INNER JOIN addon ON info.ID = addon.ID
GROUP BY info.ID
HAVING (NOT (((MIN(addon.item)) IS NOT NULL)));
```

Заменил FIRST на MIN, должно работать в постгресе

Comment: rotabor, почему то на СУБД postgresql скрипт отрабатывает с ошибками. Используете другую СУБД?
Ошибка:  (no such function: First)

Comment: Да, другая СУБД. Я думал, что это какая-то более или менее стандартная функция